# Disable Wordpress automatic text replacement of facebook in square brackets

Tags: wordpress, replace, hyperlink, shortcode

On my Wordpress page I use the Gutenberg editor to create a link. The clickable text of the link is `[facebook]` (the text *facebook* in square brackets). When I preview the page, the `[facebook]` text is not there anymore. This seemed very odd at first, but then I realized that Wordpress probably thinks that `[facebook]` is some of shortcode (or similar) and is deleting (or trying to replace) it.

My question is: How can I avoid Wordpress' removal of the written text `[facebook]` on my page?
Or in other words: How can I create a link with the text `[facebook]` in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordpress does not remove any shortcode like texts like you have "[facebook]". Wordpress will show it as it is if there is no shortcode is created.

So I think you should check this with deactivating all of your plugins.